# Dynamic inserted DIV overlapping the current content

Tags: jquery, css

I am inserting/positioning DIV after first pre tag of the page. all is working fine but it is overlapping existing content.

```
if (jQuery("pre").length > 0) {
    jQuery("#div").insertAfter($("pre:first").after());
}
```

This is how I am inserting my already exists `#div` after first pre element of page using Jquery.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle, that would be very helpful.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue. Can you include the relevant CSS to recreate the problem?

Comment: what does the overlapping look like? a screengrab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses. I have solved my issue by removing:

```
class="pull-left col-lg-4"
```

I am using bootstrap not sure why this is generating problem.